# Wordpress Child's Theme functions.php is not being read

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes

I have created a child theme from the Casper WP theme. It is called casper-child, the Casper parent theme is in a folder called "casper-master". Here is my child style.css file that is being read correctly (the background color does change to pink).

```
/*
Theme Name: Casper Child
Description: Child theme for Casper theme
Author: Grant
Template: casper-master
*/
body { background-color: pink; }
```

My problem is that my functions.php file is not being read/working.

My functions.php for my child theme is located here:
/wp-content/themes/casper-child/functions.php

The parents functions.php file is at 
/wp-content/themes/casper-master/functions.php

The code I have in my child's functions.php is:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_theme_scripts' );

function my_child_theme_scripts() {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-theme-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```

The parent theme is still not being loaded. Any ideas why? I can't seem to get anything to work in the functions.php file, no custom functions with redirects or anything. It feels like the file is not being read.

Comment: Make double, triple sure your file name is functions.php and not function.php

Comment: Thanks, Peter, it took me 2 hours to debug because of that wrong file naming...

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Wordpress documentation has `add_action` after the function, not sure if this will make a difference at all.

Also in your example there is no closing `?>`

Comment: I added the ?> and moved the add_action line under the function...still nothing. I also can not get template files to be overwritten ie: footer.php.

Comment: I don't know the ins and outs of it but themes can be written in such a way that child themes just don't work, see here:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109654

Have you ever used a child of this specific theme? Is there anyone else having a problem with Casper?

Comment: Closing ?> tag isn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Casper theme needs a specific Casper Child Theme in order to create a child theme. I found it here: http://hackersome.com/p/lacymorrow/casper

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am having a issue installing this child theme to my web host. The dash tells me this as the child theme is not even selectable.

I created my child theme on my local machine. Therefore I know it is working on my local environment. I did not change the core,only css styles and moved the navigation.

Local development running 4.1.5, host running 4.2.2

Comment: O yes- I forgot to mention, the Parent theme is there?

Answer (score 0):

Under the documentation on the top of the style.css in the -child theme capitalization creates issues on the web server, not my local environment.  For reference I am using MAMP.

For some reason the theme would not install, but then it would install sometimes. I could never activate the theme as I would always get the 'Parent theme is not installed.' It was the entire time.

I upgraded Wordpress on my local environment to the same on the host from 4.1.5 to 4.2.2. The result is that my local environment had no issues. I had the same problem.

It came to changing the capitalism in the style.css in the child theme:

From

```
/**
 Theme Name:Casper-child
 Template:Casper
 Author: Todd 
 version: 0.1
 */
```

To

```
/**
 Theme Name:Casper-child
 Template:casper
 Author: Todd
 version: 0.2
 */
```

Under Template:Casper had to be lowercased for the web host. Weird and tedious problem. Wasted few hours to figure this out, hope this helps someone :)

Comment: And then you waste hours to learn that the theme for which your client even paid 60 bucks actually has this error in it... Another piece of proof showing how much trouble you can avoid in developing all of your own custom stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, yes this is a little detail that will screw you up moving from MAMP to LAMP.  OSX isn't case sensitive.

"casper" and "Casper" are the same to OSX, but different on Linux.